# Getting object array data

Tags: java

So i first declare this object of a class:

```
static enterprise[] en = new enterprise[10];
```

Then, inside main:

```
for(int i=0;i<=9;i++){
    System.out.println("Insert name of the " + (i+1) + "ª enterprise");
    en[i] = new enterprise(i);
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    en[i].setName(scanner.next());
    System.out.println(en[i].Name);
    }
```

And then, in another method of the same class:

```
for(int i = 0; i<=9;i++){
    System.out.println(en[i].index + "- " + en[i].Name);
}
```

So if at first I inserted on the first enterprise A, second B, C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J.. I should get as an output 1 A 2 B etc, but I get 9 J ten times. why does this happen?

Edit: here is the enterprise class: http://pastebin.com/gUCWRRgK

Comment: `static` fields are shared among instances, so remove the `static` modifier from those fields you want to have independent values per instance. See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html), the relevant part of the Sun Java Tutorials.

Answer (score 1):

It's because your fields are declared static.

```
public class enterprise {
    static String Name;
    static int index;
```

When a field is static it means that variable is associated with the class. Static variables cannot have different  values for each instance.

It should be this:

```
public class enterprise {
    String Name;
    int index;
```

Comment: Hmm, but now I get error on eclipse on another class named player, I have a total of 4 classes, player, enterprise, enemy and main. Eclipse says that amount, name and value must be static

Comment: Here is the exact error: Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field enterprise.Name
And here the code: http://pastebin.com/YHqNZdWZ

Comment: @zyngawow: Oh wait, you don't actually have an instance there which is why you get the error. In that case you do need those two fields to be static (but only those two). But this code smells bad. Those fields should probably should be instance variables on your player instead, assuming it's some sort of count of the total value the player owns.

Comment: There is only one player instance, but multiple enemies and multiple enterprises. Could you explain it a bit better?

Comment: @zyngawow: If `total` is the total for your player, then you should make it an instance variable on your player. If it's a total for your entire universe then you could make a new class called `Universe` and put the field there. It's a very bad idea to have public static non-final fields. They're Java's equivalent of global variables, and global variables are usually considered to be a Very Bad Thing.

Comment: Hmm.. now, i must have amount, value and name static, but id works when it is displayed

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14825/discussion-between-zyngawow-and-mark-byers)

Answer (score 0):

That's because you made your variables static. Remove the static keywords and it'll work. `static` does not work in Java like it does in C.